# High CPU usage systemd+

Tags: wireless, 18.04, systemd, cpu-load

I updated my Ubuntu from 16.04 to 18.04. After the update I noticed that the CPU usage was going crazy for no reason. Here is the result of "top"

`PID  USER    PR   NI   VIRT    RES    SHR S   %CPU  %MEM  TIME+
 721 systemd+  20   0   72276   7816   5500 R  99.3  0.1 151:19.06 systemd-re+ 
 2603 dnsmasq  20   0   52880   2944   2560 S  46.4  0.0  70:04.83 dnsmasq

 1111 root     20   0  444472  48516  30056 S   2.3  0.8   1:35.29 Xorg

11077 ciani    20   0  666772  36544  27504 S   2.0  0.6   0:00.93 gnome-term+`

The problem seems related to the wifi. If I turn it off the CPU usage goes back to normal. I found some related questions

[QuestionCPUusage](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1035528/ubuntu-18-04-systemd-udevd-uses-high-cpu-conflict-with-nvidia-graphics)

but none of the solutions I found worked for me. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [systemd-resolve high cpu usage after update to 17.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/909591/systemd-resolve-high-cpu-usage-after-update-to-17-04)